Error in {task 1 failed - [readValues] cannot read values in R doParallel "foreach"
I am trying to speed up an intervisibility calculation between landscape viewpoints (X, Y, height), using a rasterprofile and line of sight functions over a digital elevation model. I ran a large-scale project like this on 1000 objects (ie. 1000 x 1000 calculations) 2 months back and successfully parallelized, shortening processing time more than 10fold. I am now reusing the same code on a slightly fewer features (341 x 1200) in a neighboring region. The parallelisation runs to the end as the counter shows, function cansee() is defined locally. My problem is that if I calculate intervisibility for more than 10 x 1200 features, the function fails to write out the final result, giving instead "[readValues] cannot read values" error, as you can see below:
cl <- makeCluster(10) # I have 16 cores so this seems to not be an overkill
registerDoParallel(cl)

ie_table <- foreach (i = 1:nrow(origin), # 40 rows here
                     .combine = 'rbind',
                     .packages = c("data.table", "raster")) %do% {  
  print(i)
  foreach(e = 1:nrow(target),  # 1200 rows here
          .combine = 'rbind',.packages = c("data.table", "raster")) %dopar% {
  print(e)
  result <-  cansee(Y35, origin[i,1:2], target[e,1:2], h1 = origin[i,3], h2 = target[e,3])
  result_row <- c(i,e, result)
  }
}

stopCluster(cl)

Meanwhile the console outputs:
[1] 1

[1] 35
[1] 36
[1] 37
[1] 38
[1] 39
[1] 40
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "task 1 failed - "[readValues] cannot read values""

When the error started appearing, I tried reducing the number of origins to see if there was something wrong with the data.
I started seeing the following warning as the parallelisation proceeded, at random places in the calculation:
# SIZE REDUCED FOR TESTING PURPOSES 
origin <- origin[1:10,] 

# nesting both i and e with foreach 
ie_table <- foreach (i= 1:nrow(origin), 
                      .combine = 'rbind',
                      .packages = c("data.table", "raster")) %do% {  
   print(i)
   foreach( e= 1:nrow(target), .combine = 'rbind',.packages = c("data.table", "raster")) %dopar% {
   print(e)
   result <-  cansee(Y35, origin[i,1:2], target[e,1:2], h1 = origin[i,3], h2 = target[e,3])
   result_row <- c(i,e, result)
   }
}

[1] 1
Warning: closing unused connection 12 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 11 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 10 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 9 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 8 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 7 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 6 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 5 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 4 (<-Zenbook:11102)
Warning: closing unused connection 3 (<-Zenbook:11102)
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4

The warning does not prevent the completion of this calculation, but perhaps is another symptom of my problem? Again, if I calculate on 10 x 1200 values, the ie_table is complete with 12000 observations, raising to 20 x1200, I get "[readValues] cannot read values error".
Any ideas?
I am working in projected CRS (epsg32635), raster contains all points. The origin and target point data look like this:
> origin
           X       Y   h
 [1,] 453727.1 4706737 1.5
 [2,] 452999.1 4707739 2.0
 [3,] 452997.0 4707823 2.0
 [4,] 454596.0 4707388 2.0
 [5,] 453591.3 4706447 2.0
 [6,] 453884.8 4706455 1.0
 [7,] 453042.8 4705682 1.0
 [8,] 455169.2 4708542 6.0

And jsut to unpack the cansee() function, here is its definition
cansee <- function(r, xy1, xy2, h1=0, h2=0){
### can xy1 see xy2 on DEM r?
### r is a DEM (Y35) in same x,y, z units
### xy1 and xy2 are 2-length vectors of x,y coords
### h1 and h2 are extra height offsets (ie. feature heights)
###  (eg observer at the viewpoint, etc)
    xyz = rasterprofile(r, xy1, xy2)
    np = nrow(xyz)-1
    h1 = xyz$z[1] + h1
    h2 = xyz$z[np] + h2
    hpath = h1 + (0:np)*(h2-h1)/np
    return(!any(hpath < xyz$z))
} 


The warnings are harmless only unused connections to your workers closing. The problem is in "cansee" but, since it can't be viewed, no advice is possible.

Thank you, Ric. I realize the warnings are not the core issue, the [readValues] is. I added cansee() function definition above.
